# your sql server installation is either currupt or has baan tempered with (unable to load SQLBoot.dll)

Tags: sql-server-2008

we are getting this error on live server and need urgent reply.

**"your sql server installation is either currupt or has baan tempered with (unable to load SQLBoot.dll)"**

Thanks.

Comment: also getting this error too "Your SQL Server installation is either corrupt or has been tampered with (unable to load SQLBOOT.DLL). Please uninstall then re-run setup to correct this problem" but we cannot install sql server again it will take too much time with backups also.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall SQL. Then, scan your system for viruses, disk errors, etc.

For now, you probably need to switch over to your backup server if you've got one. If not, throw up the "Under Maintenance" webpage.

Comment: Sorry the first response was really short. There's not a lot of detail in the question and I'm a bit out of practice and had to teach a class. If something has corrupted or tampered with your SQL, as the error message suggests, then my first concern would be "Was I hacked?" Don't be a Sony. Take yourself off-line, d/c the computer from the internet, and scan the crap out of it. If you're wrong, then you get to write a reassuring message to your customers, "We had a disc error, but in order to ensure your data was safe, we took the server offline until we could be sure we hadn't been hacked."